# Why was Chattanooga the host of the 2015 NPSL National Championship game?

Tags: football

On August 8th, 2015, Chattanooga FC played host to the NPSL final game at Finley Stadium in Chattanooga, TN.

However, they finished with a lower points per game record than their opponents the New York Cosmos B.

Why was Chattanooga allowed to host the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Chattanooga FC Website](http://www.chattanoogafc.com/news/2015-npsl-national-championship-coming-to-chattanooga), New York Cosmos B did indeed have the better record, and therefore right of refusal for home-field advantage, but they agreed to play the match in Chattanooga.

> Immediately following Saturday’s matches, work began to determine the
>   best location for the 2015 Championship game. While their #1 seed
>   gives the NY Cosmos B the right of refusal for home-field advantage,
>   Chattanooga was able to secure the home field advantage, with the
>   Championship to be played at Finley Stadium’s Davenport Field on
>   Saturday, August 8 at 7:30pm.

They also give a couple of reasons why NY Cosmos agreed to this, which could be summarized as "bums on seats".

> While there were a number of factors at play, according to CFC board
>   member Tim Kelly, one of the most persuading arguments to bring the
>   game to Chattanooga was the combination of a world-class soccer
>   facility and the strongest fan base in the NPSL.
>
> “In a league where most teams enjoy the regular support of a few
>   hundred fans, our fan-base here Chattanooga is envied—and our
>   partnership with Finley stadium insures a great experience for fans
>   and players alike. Teams want to play here.”

Reading between the lines, especially the words "work began" in the first quote, I think that means that the teams negotiated that a share of that gate money ([18,227 fans attended](http://www.chattanoogafc.com/news/chattanooga-fc-falls-3-2-in-ot-in-national-title-match), a national record for an amateur match) went also to NY Cosmos B, and this share was more than they would have got by holding the match at home.